# Deep link in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, deep-linking

I newbie in kivy iam making app so that like in youtube there will be a video link so that then we click on it we directly open youtube and plays the video like http://youtube.com/some video. I want like that http://my_app.com/videos , so is there any way like that to create deep links in kivy